# Seeking West Punjabi learning resources

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, electronic-resources, physical-resources, punjabi

I wish to learn the Punjabi language.

From what I understand, Western Punjabi (spoken in Pakistan) is the traditional Punjabi language that Punjabis spoke before the Partition of India (which created Pakistan), and Eastern Punjabi is spoken in Punjab, India

Please tell me where I can learn Western Punjabi (using Gurmukhi script, not Arabic script)

I searched Rosetta Stone, and they do not offer Punjabi at all.

Then I read reviews of [Pimsleur Punjabi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1442336137) and they say this teaches a formal way of speaking Punjabi.

Comment: Are you looking specifically for online courses/materials? Do they need to be free?

Comment: @Flimzy I can pay nominal fee

Comment: @Rhonda: Thanks. And what about my other question? Do you want specifically online courses, or are any learning materials (books, classes) of interest to you?

Comment: @Flimzy I'm looking for online courses, books, classes, or even apps. I have andriod. BTW, I wish to learn the way of speaking in West Punjab, but using Gurmukhi script, not Arabic script. I updated original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, some linguists consider Western Panjabi/Punjabi and Eastern Panjabi/Punjabi as dialects of the same language. When you look for learning materials and grammars, they refer to "Punjabi" or "Panjabi", not to any of its variants. For example:

- [Free Punjabi Lessons and Courses](http://multilingualbooks.com/freelessons-punjabi.html) listed by MultilingualBooks.com.
- *[Learn Punjabi](http://multilingualbooks.com/punjabi.html)* Talk Now! series. (no date)
- Mangat Rai Bhardwaj: *[Colloquial Panjabi: The Complete Course for Beginners](https://www.routledge.com/Colloquial-Panjabi-The-Complete-Course-for-Beginners/Bhardwaj/p/book/9781138958616)*, 2nd edition. Routledge, 2012.
- Mangat Bhardwaj: *[Panjabi: A Comprehensive Grammar](https://www.routledge.com/Panjabi-A-Comprehensive-Grammar/Bhardwaj/p/book/9781138793866)*. Routledge, 2016.
- Tej Bhatia: *[Punjabi](https://www.routledge.com/Punjabi/Bhatia/p/book/9780415589932)*. Descriptive Grammars. Routledge, 1994.
- Narindara Dule: *[A pedagogical grammar of Punjabi](http://www.worldcat.org/title/pedagogical-grammar-of-punjabi/oclc/24012506&referer=brief_results)*. Patiala : Indian Institute of Language Studies, 1989.
- Motia Bhatia: *[An intensive course in Punjabi : dialogues, drills, exercises, vocabulary, notes on grammar, and word index](http://www.worldcat.org/title/intensive-course-in-punjabi-dialogues-drills-exercises-vocabulary-notes-on-grammar-and-word-index/oclc/17108304&referer=brief_results)*. Mysore : Central Institute of Indian Languages, 1985.
- C. Shackle: *[Punjabi](http://www.worldcat.org/title/punjabi/oclc/339888&referer=brief_results)*.     London, St. Paul's House, 1972.
- Thomas Bailey Grahame (1872-1942): *[Panjabi Grammar. A Brief Grammar of Panjabi as Spoken in the Wazirabad District](https://www.wdl.org/es/item/9704/)*. 1904.

I could not find Punjabi, Panjabi or Western Punjabi in the [list of free FSI courses](http://www.101languages.net/fsi-courses/) or on [lingvopolis](http://lingvo.info/en/lingvopolis).

Comment: How interesting, especially  `Thomas Bailey Grahame (1872-1942): Panjabi Grammar. A Brief Grammar of Panjabi as Spoken in the Wazirabad District. 1904.` This was pre-partitioned Punjab (before 1947)!